# После метода main()

Tags: java, jvm

Появился такой вопрос.

```
public final class Launcher {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
            // create and run many threads...
      }
}
```

При запуске приложения внутри `main()` создается и запускается куча потоков и главный поток не дожидается их завершения (нет `join()`). Эти потоки делают что-то тяжелое. Главный поток уже вышел из `main()`. Что теперь делает jvm? Я знаю, что она дожидается всех потоков не демонов. Мне интересно делает ли она что-то для своего завершения? Или просто ждет? Видел, что появляется поток `DestroyJavaVM`, он для чего?

И что делать, если хочется после выхода из `main()` убить приложение? Запустить thread-таймер, который при этом демон и в нём сделать `System.exit(0)`? Нормальное ли это решение?

Стопроцентно ли `System.exit(0)` убивает jvm? Или есть случаи, когда `exit` может повиснуть? Если, например, `shutdownHook` делает что-то тяжелое, то jvm будет его ждать? В каких случаях `shutdownHook` вообще не дергается (помимо `Runtime.halt()` и `kill -9`)?

Извиняюсь за кучу вопросов, но просто много чего непонятно и найти инфу сложно. Все одно и тоже пишут.

Comment: Вопросы занятные. Вот только на часть из них вы уже и сами ответили)

Answer (score 2):

> Что теперь делает jvm?

Продолжает выполнять другие потоки. Раз есть потоки - значит процесс еще работает.

> Мне интересно делает ли она что-то для своего завершения? Или просто ждет? Видел, что появляется поток DestroyJavaVM, он для чего?

Пока есть потоки - процесс работы продолжается. DestroyJavaVM выгружает виртуальную машину из памяти. Кстати, до версии 1.2 только основной поток мог вызывать DestroyJavaVM,но в следующих версиях это ограничение было снято - теперь это может делать любой поток.

> И что делать, если хочется после выхода из main() убить приложение? Запустить thread-таймер, который при этом демон и в нём сделать System.exit(0)? Нормальное ли это решение?

Лучше предусмотреть логику внутри других потоков, что их могут прервать (т.е. обработку interruptedException и флага isInterrupted), а из основного потока (или специально созданного) "просить" потоки завершиться. Это если нужно чтобы данные не были испорчены или сохранены в промежуточном состоянии. Обрабатывая прерывание (и флаг прерывания) изнутри потоков можно контролировать, когда именно прерваться потоку (возможно лучше доделать какой-то кусок работы - а потом выйти)

> Стопроцентно ли System.exit(0) убивает jvm? Или есть случаи, когда exit может повиснуть?

SecurityManager может не дать так просто завершить JVM если у него метод checkExit переопределен.

> Если, например, shutdownHook делает что-то тяжелое, то jvm будет его ждать?

Не всегда. Например если выключаете компьютер - то ОС его точно ждать не будет бесконечно - только определенное время.
 Поэтому туда "тяжелое" не рекомендуется засовывать - вроде IO операций или многопоточности с дедлоками ("Shutdown hooks should also finish their work quickly.")

> В каких случаях shutdownHook вообще не дергается (помимо Runtime.halt() и kill -9)?

Ну при внутренних ошибках, которые крашат саму JVM

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но есть несколько вопросов. `Продолжает выполнять другие потоки` - разве jvm вообще имеет к этому отношение?? Операционка же шедулит потоки, процессы. И jvm вряд ли что-то делает именно для выполнения потоков, нет? `DestroyJavaVM выгружает виртуальную машину из памяти` можете чуть подробнее сказать, что за выгрузка и зачем нужна? `Лучше предусмотреть логику внутри других потоков, что их могут прервать` - допустим есть системный вызов, который блокирует поток, и не дает ему обработать флажок (например socket `read()`), то как завершить работу jvm?

Comment: ну сама JVM тоже процесс со своими потоками - например, тот же GC должен работать. Может не так понимаю вопрос, конечно.

Comment: DestroyJavaVM - ну хотя бы надо служебные потоки остановить надо

Comment: если поток заблокирован на IO - нужно искать другое решение - но может лучше этот поток демоном сделать?

Comment: если посмотреть в исходниках openjdk то можно например найти уведомление модуля трассировки https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u-backup-31-oct-2018/blob/52fdb973403401f4073df3849793e1415ca2bc93/hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/java.cpp

Comment: Очень не факт что лучше его демоном сделать. Помимо блокирующей операции поток может еще что-то делать. Обычная ситуация для потока из пула, который куда-то делает http запрос и делает что-то с респонсом. И вот при обработке респонса нужно обработать interrupt. Если http-клиент асинхронный, то все норм, а если нет? делать два пула - один с демонами для http запросов, другой с нормальной обработкой прерываний? жестковато

Comment: да, GC должен работать, но создание потока это не прерогатива jvm. JVM лишь просит ос создать поток. А уже операционка делает системный вызов и создает поток (в linux вызов `clone()` с передачей указателя на выполняемую функцию). Вопрос именно в том, что имелось ввиду под `Jvm продолжает выполнять другие потоки`. Не подумайте что я придираюсь, просто интересно докопаться до сути)

Comment: `DestroyJavaVM` создается после выхода из `main()`. Дальше идет ожидание потоков не демонов. Но этот поток все равно висит и че то делает. Мне кажется, что там `join()` с таймаутом и после выхода по таймауту он чекает надо ли убить jvm и если надо, то начинает стопить потоки, если не надо - опять уходит в `join(timeout)`. Но руки посмотреть исходники openjdk все никак не доходят, поэтому думал мб у кого-то дошли и он расскажет)